# Delphi 7: Actual reason for a data breakpoint warning

Tags: delphi, delphi-7, breakpoints

On Delphi 7, I recived a warning message: "Setting a Data Breakpoint on a stack location may cause your program or system to become unstable. Set breakpoint anyway?". The short description of this message **does not** explain the reason why the program (or system) may become unstable. It only says that it may happen.

I would like to ask you for a concrete explanation with the reason why/when the program (or system) will be unstable.

Comment: What do you mean by "how can I prevent it?" Also, what problem are you encountering. Why don't you just close the warning message, and proceed. What happens when you do that?

Comment: I removed this part of the question, it is not the most important. For me importent is a concrete explanation of the reason

Comment: If guess that the stack is used and reused so frequently that breaking on its modification would likely render the debugger unusable. Hard to see how system could be affected. Maybe the warning text dates from older versions of windows.

Comment: Still it is not the answer to my question ;-)

Comment: Because the breakpoint still remains in effect after the point of interest leaves execution. Watching for who-knows what.

Comment: Why don't you ask Embarcadero. I will leave you alone now with that attitude why do you think we will help you.

Comment: Did you try [the docs](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Seattle/en/Data_Breakpoint_is_set_on_a_stack_location)?

Comment: Actual reason?  Suppose you place a data breakpoint on a local variable of a procedure/function.  Locals are allocated  on the stack.  Once the procedure/function exits, the stack space used by the local can now be used by some other routine which is free to re-use the space.  If the other routine changes data at the address of your local, what's supposed to happen then?

Comment: @Martyn - that explains why the stack is not a good place to put a Data Breakpoint, It explains how the debugger could be made next-to-useless.  But it doesn't explain how it could cause a program or the system to become unstable (I can't see any way that it could - the data breakpoint is only reading that location, not modifying it).  Explaining the problems with data breakpoints in the stack was probably too much to fit into a simple error message, so they perhaps instead opted to simplify with a "SCARE THEM OFF" message approach ?  Maybe ?

Comment: @Deltics:  Indeed.  Iirc (but it's 20+ years since I did any asm), a "normal" breakpoint involves temporarily patching an Int3 instruction where the breakpoint is supposed to occur, which is straightforward enough.  But I can't immediately see how a Data Breakpoint on the stack would work, seeing as where the data would be would depend (?) at how execution led to the routine being called.  I imagine you're right about the scare message.

Comment: @Martyn - Intuitively I would expect a Data Breakpoint to work very differently (... *does some research* ...) and it turns out that they do.  :)  They are supported at the *hardware* level, as explained here (and elsewhere):  http://www.nynaeve.net/?p=80  .  Disclosure:  I was confusing in my mind the behaviour of a *Data* Breakpoint and a simple *Conditional* Breakpoint, but the principle of "process protection" remains the same (confining the instability to the debugger, rather than the program or the entire system).

Comment: Despite saying that my comments were not the answer you accepted an answer saying exactly the same thing. Nice.

Comment: Your answer was not the same. Last paragraph of the accepted answer was an answer for me.

Comment: @Annabelle Final sentence of my comment. Obviously Deltics fleshed it out, but he's saying exactly the same as me.

Comment: In general, as your comment is helpful I added (+1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A Data Breakpoint is triggered by a write operation to memory at a specified location.  Detecting these operations, whether by use of a hardware breakpoint or other techniques, cannot - to my knowledge - cause a program, let alone an entire system, to become unstable.

There are however problems with creating data breakpoints in the stack area.  These problems can lead to *debugger behaviours* which are almost certainly undesirable and could be considered "instability", due to the volume and frequency of breakpoints rendering the debugger unusable.

But this is the *only* extent to which the "system" or the "program" can be made unstable.

The error message is most likely using abbreviated language which is arguably misleading in an attempt to convey this in terms which are suitable for a short, terse error message, since the actual, accurate explanation is both harder to explain and perhaps less likely to be understood by many developers.

It is also possible that placing a Data Breakpoint in the stack *did* have the potential to cause wider system problems pre-Win32 (I don't know for sure, but I can imagine it is possible - it was certainly easier for a program failure to crash an entire system under Win16); i.e. that this message is a hang-over from Delphi 1 and was simply not updated to reflect the greater protection that processes enjoy under Win32.